# Athena geospatial SQL joins never complete

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, geospatial, presto

A very basic geospatial join, based on [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-example-queries.html), times out every time.

The table `polygons` contains 340K polygons, while `points` contains 5K rows with latitude/longitude pairs (and an ID). Both are single .csv files in S3.

Query:

```
SELECT poly.geometry, p.id
FROM polygons as poly
CROSS JOIN points as p
WHERE ST_CONTAINS (ST_POLYGON(poly.geometry), ST_POINT(p.lon, p.lat));
```

The SQL query above never completes in the default 30-minute Athena query time limit.

I've found vanilla Athena queries on large-ish data sets are fairly performant, but I'm not sure whether the geospatial functionality can handle (million x million) joins, let alone (billion x million) joins.

Thought I'd ask before moving back to EMR+Spark solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Athena service is based on [Presto 0.172](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/). That version did not have geospatial join, so your query if single-node cross-join + filter.

Newer Presto versions have the optimization so they can execute such query in a distributed manner.

Besides going back to EMR, you can try [Starburst Presto for AWS](https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/) which gives you easy to launch best Presto version prepackaged for AWS. (note: I work for Starburst)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pre filter in polygons table like this

... where ST_Buffer(ST_GeometryFromText( shape_wkt) , 5000.0 * 360.0 / (2.0 * pi() * cos( radians(latitud) ) * 6400000.0)    ))

5000.0 =  radius distance in meters